# How do you setup npm on lubuntu

Tags: node.js

I am trying to do a simple

```
sudo npm install jsdom
```

but I get the following [error](http://pastebin.com/tx5F9RsD). I used [these](http://howtonode.org/how-to-install-nodejs) instructions for installing node. This was a clean install of lubuntu. The entire setup is listed in the following steps:

1. install lubuntu and virtual box guest additions
2. sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
3. sudo apt-get install g++ curl libssl-dev apache2-utils
4. sudo apt-get install git-core
5. cd .. to the root directory
6. sudo chmod 0777 / (I know this is completely insane. It's just a test virtual OS).
7. git clone git://github.com/ry/node.git (this creates /node with files inside)
8. cd node
9. ./configure
10. make
11. sudo make install
12. sudo npm install jsdom

I have used

```
sudo npm -f install --nodedir=/node jsdom
```

but even then if I try to use the module in a script it crashes saying there is no implementation for the module.

Comment: The particular article you reference is two years old! Have you tried installing a binary from here? http://nodejs.org/download/ Have you tried installing Node with lubuntu's package manager?

Comment: You could also try nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `pre` version of Node, which is kinda beta version, which may have compability issues. Also, your script says that you should supply --nodedir= but you supply it to `/node` which is not probably the right place.

Find out where is your node installation at by `which node` or `which nodejs` and point to that directory in your install command.

Comment: i thought it would just work. windows has spoiled me. i uninstalled and followed these instructions http://slopjong.de/2012/10/31/how-to-install-the-latest-nodejs-in-ubuntu/ and now it works. thanks!